# List items in MongoDB array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to list a series of paragraphs I have stored as an array in a document field "body". Where I have x items in the array, it outputs the whole field x times. If someone can point me in the right direction I'd so appreciate it. I know the issue is just where I have #{pages.body} at the end, because obviously that returns the whole field, but I'm not sure how to change it.

route:

```
exports.cont = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('contents');
            collection.find({href:req.params.href},{},function(e,docs){
                res.render('cont', {
                    "cont" : docs
                });
            });
        };
};
```

display page in Jade:

```
each pages, i in cont
    .box
        h1 #{pages.title}
            .img
                img.body(src="#{pages.img}")
            .text
                each para, i in pages.body
                    p #{pages.body}
```

Comment: Fixed it!! I turned the array under "body" into a series of subdocuments with { text: "paragraph text..." } and in the .text div changed to:

    each paragraph, i in pages.body
        p #{paragraph.text}

Hope that helps someone at some point!

Comment: Since you worked out a solution for your own question, you can also post a cleaned up version as an answer below (i.e. including the example of the corrected template).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
each pages, i in cont
    .box
        h1 #{pages.title}
            .img
                img.body(src="#{pages.img}")
            .text
                each paragraph, i in pages.body
                    p #{paragraph.text}
```

MongoDB document setup:

```
{ 
    img: "xxxxxx",
    body:
        [
            { text: "xxxxxxx" },
            { text: "xxxxxxx" },
            { text: "xxxxxxx" }
        ]
}
```

If you want the option of HTML formatting in each paragraph, just replace the # before {paragraph.text} with !